# Explanation for error "Incoming request was redirected to the wrong geo! Current geo: EUDB, Target geo: EMEA" in Bot Framework Teams Bots?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

Starting May 13th, 2022 around 3 PM UTC, we are seeing several of our previously functional Teams bots built on the bot framework failing to send messages to users.

The following error appears in the Azure Portal.  The same bots have been functional for 1 year plus and work fine earlier today.

Any insights on what this error means? Is EUDB a new region for the purpose of Service URLs?

[image]

Comment: Affected multiple clients, lasted about 90 minutes, and then disappeared without any changes made in the bots.   Would still be interested in an explanation on what causes this error, and what EUDB region is?    Nearest acronym I can find is EU Data Boundary so suspect some Microsoft software update rollout that caused this and was pulled back

Comment: Please refer: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/security-compliance-and-identity/eu-data-boundary-for-the-microsoft-cloud-frequently-asked/ba-p/2329098   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-faqs#traffic-manager-geographic-traffic-routing-method

Comment: Thanks.  How does this tie into traffic sent from from a Teams bot to a user's service URL using the botframework?  The issue reported in the post lasted 90 minutes and got automatically  resolved automatically without any changes on the bot end or user end (i.e neither changed any of their setting).

Comment: Could you please confirm if there was any recent issue ?Please share the Bot Id and Timestamp when it occurs again.